# Steam is unable to find mangohud when included in launch option

Tags: steam, linux

So I've installed Steam using `Flathub` to play game on Linux with [`mangohud`](https://github.com/flightlessmango/MangoHud) to display FPS with CPU, GPU stat as an overlay.

And in the documentation, to display the overlay on games, all I have to do is add `mangohud %command%`, so I tried it with one game to test if it would work.

But when I click `Play`, it just closes immediately. No crash messages, no error popup. To find out what went wrong, I run Steam using `flatpak run com.valvesoftware.Steam` so I can see the verbose output in the terminal, and when I started the game, I saw that Steam was unable to find mangohud:

```
/bin/sh: line 1: mangohud: command not found
```

The only problem is that `mangohud` has been added to `/usr/bin`, and the directory is in `PATH` env variable, so any program should be able to invoke `mangohud`. And just to make sure, I've tried the command with both `sh`, `bash` and `zsh` shell, and it all run perfectly.

So first off, thinking that it might be a permission issue (which is common for program installed using flathub), I've run:

```
sudo flatpak override com.valvesoftware.Steam --filesystem=/usr/bin
```

but it didn't work.

Next up, thinking that Steam might be unable to access `mangohud` directly, I've used the absolute path: `/usr/bin/mangohud %command%`, but still, Steam said that it can't find it:

```
/bin/sh: line 1: /usr/bin/mangohud: command not found
```

And as a final attempt, I've restarted my computer, re-compile `mangohud` and re-tried all the method above, but still, it doesn't work.

I think the reason might be related to the fact that Steam was installed using Flatpak, which might be restricting access to certain program or certain directory.

So how can I resolve this issue?

**FULL LOG** (some information like username are hidden for privacy reason):

```
INFO:root:https://github.com/flathub/com.valvesoftware.Steam/wiki
INFO:root:Will set XDG dirs prefix to /home/REDACTED/.var/app/com.valvesoftware.Steam
DEBUG:root:Checking input devices permissions
INFO:root:Overriding TZ to Asia/Ho_Chi_Minh
steam.sh[2]: Running Steam on org.freedesktop.platform 22.08 64-bit
steam.sh[2]: STEAM_RUNTIME is enabled automatically
setup.sh[77]: Steam runtime environment up-to-date!
steam.sh[2]: Steam client's requirements are satisfied
[2022-11-30 18:58:26] Startup - updater built Nov 17 2022 02:42:14
[2022-11-30 18:58:26] Startup - Steam Client launched with: '/home/REDACTED/.var/app/com.valvesoftware.Steam/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam' '-no-cef-sandbox'
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1668654564)
Looks like steam didn't shutdown cleanly, scheduling immediate update check
[2022-11-30 18:58:26] Loading cached metrics from disk (/home/REDACTED/.var/app/com.valvesoftware.Steam/.local/share/Steam/package/steam_client_metrics.bin)
[2022-11-30 18:58:26] Using the following download hosts for Public, Realm steamglobal
[2022-11-30 18:58:26] 1. https://client-update.akamai.steamstatic.com, /, Realm 'steamglobal', weight was 1000, source = 'update_hosts_cached.vdf'
[2022-11-30 18:58:26] 2. https://cdn.cloudflare.steamstatic.com, /client/, Realm 'steamglobal', weight was 1, source = 'update_hosts_cached.vdf'
[2022-11-30 18:58:26] 3. http://media.steampowered.com, /client/, Realm 'steamglobal', weight was 1, source = 'baked in'
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1668654564)
[2022-11-30 18:58:26] Checking for update on startup
[2022-11-30 18:58:26] Checking for available updates...
[2022-11-30 18:58:26] Downloading manifest: https://client-update.akamai.steamstatic.com/steam_client_ubuntu12
[2022-11-30 18:58:26] Manifest download: send request
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1668654564)
[2022-11-30 18:58:27] Manifest download: waiting for download to finish
[2022-11-30 18:58:28] Manifest download: finished
[2022-11-30 18:58:28] Download skipped: /steam_client_ubuntu12 version 1668654564, installed version 1668654564, existing pending version 0
[2022-11-30 18:58:28] Nothing to do
[2022-11-30 18:58:28] Verifying installation...
[2022-11-30 18:58:28] Performing checksum verification of executable files
[2022-11-30 18:58:30] Verification complete
Loaded SDL version 2.25.0-p7648887
XRRGetOutputInfo Workaround: initialized with override: 0 real: 0xee3308f0
XRRGetCrtcInfo Workaround: initialized with override: 0 real: 0xee32f1c0
Gtk-Message: 18:58:30.820: Failed to load module "pk-gtk-module"
ComputeStartupMode: found registry default startup mode: 0Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1668654564)
steamwebhelper.sh[170]: Runtime for steamwebhelper: defaulting to /home/REDACTED/.var/app/com.valvesoftware.Steam/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_64/steam-runtime-heavy
steamwebhelper.sh[170]: Running under Flatpak, disabling sandbox
steamwebhelper.sh[170]: CEF sandbox already disabled
Could not connect to X session manager: None of the authentication protocols specified are supported
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1668654564)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1668654564)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1668654564)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1668654564)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1668654564)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1668654564)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1668654564)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1668654564)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1668654564)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1668654564)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1668654564)
CAppInfoCacheReadFromDiskThread took 546 milliseconds to initialize
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1668654564)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1668654564)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1668654564)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1668654564)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1668654564)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1668654564)
Could not connect to X session manager: None of the authentication protocols specified are supported
Could not connect to X session manager: None of the authentication protocols specified are supported
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1668654564)

(steam:155): Gtk-WARNING **: 18:58:33.915: gtk_disable_setlocale() must be called before gtk_init()
MESA-INTEL: warning: Performance support disabled, consider sysctl dev.i915.perf_stream_paranoid=0
MESA-INTEL: warning: Performance support disabled, consider sysctl dev.i915.perf_stream_paranoid=0
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1668654564)
local (potentially out of sync) copy of roaming config loaded - 1114 bytes.
BRefreshApplicationsInLibrary 1: 0ms
roaming config store loaded successfully - 1114 bytes.
migrating temporary roaming config store
Could not connect to X session manager: None of the authentication protocols specified are supported
Could not connect to X session manager: None of the authentication protocols specified are supported
Could not connect to X session manager: None of the authentication protocols specified are supported
Could not connect to X session manager: None of the authentication protocols specified are supported
Could not connect to X session manager: None of the authentication protocols specified are supported
Could not connect to X session manager: None of the authentication protocols specified are supported
Could not connect to X session manager: None of the authentication protocols specified are supported
Could not connect to X session manager: None of the authentication protocols specified are supported
Could not connect to X session manager: None of the authentication protocols specified are supported
Could not connect to X session manager: None of the authentication protocols specified are supported
Could not connect to X session manager: None of the authentication protocols specified are supported
Could not connect to X session manager: None of the authentication protocols specified are supported
Could not connect to X session manager: None of the authentication protocols specified are supported
Could not connect to X session manager: None of the authentication protocols specified are supported
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1668654564)
Could not connect to X session manager: None of the authentication protocols specified are supported
Could not connect to X session manager: None of the authentication protocols specified are supported
Could not connect to X session manager: None of the authentication protocols specified are supported
Could not connect to X session manager: None of the authentication protocols specified are supported
Could not connect to X session manager: None of the authentication protocols specified are supported
Could not connect to X session manager: None of the authentication protocols specified are supported
Could not connect to X session manager: None of the authentication protocols specified are supported
Could not connect to X session manager: None of the authentication protocols specified are supported
Could not connect to X session manager: None of the authentication protocols specified are supported
Could not connect to X session manager: None of the authentication protocols specified are supported
Could not connect to X session manager: None of the authentication protocols specified are supported
Could not connect to X session manager: None of the authentication protocols specified are supported
Failed to init SteamVR because it isn't installed
Could not connect to X session manager: None of the authentication protocols specified are supported
Could not connect to X session manager: None of the authentication protocols specified are supported
Could not connect to X session manager: None of the authentication protocols specified are supported
Could not connect to X session manager: None of the authentication protocols specified are supported
Could not connect to X session manager: None of the authentication protocols specified are supported
Could not connect to X session manager: None of the authentication protocols specified are supported
Could not connect to X session manager: None of the authentication protocols specified are supported
Could not connect to X session manager: None of the authentication protocols specified are supported
Could not connect to X session manager: None of the authentication protocols specified are supported
Could not connect to X session manager: None of the authentication protocols specified are supported
Could not connect to X session manager: None of the authentication protocols specified are supported
Could not connect to X session manager: None of the authentication protocols specified are supported
Could not connect to X session manager: None of the authentication protocols specified are supported
Could not connect to X session manager: None of the authentication protocols specified are supported
Could not connect to X session manager: None of the authentication protocols specified are supported
Could not connect to X session manager: None of the authentication protocols specified are supported
Could not connect to X session manager: None of the authentication protocols specified are supported
Could not connect to X session manager: None of the authentication protocols specified are supported
Could not connect to X session manager: None of the authentication protocols specified are supported
Could not connect to X session manager: None of the authentication protocols specified are supported
Could not connect to X session manager: None of the authentication protocols specified are supported
Could not connect to X session manager: None of the authentication protocols specified are supported
ExecCommandLine: "'/home/REDACTED/.var/app/com.valvesoftware.Steam/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam' '-no-cef-sandbox'"
System startup time: 10.45 seconds
BuildCompleteAppOverviewChange: 171 apps
RegisterForAppOverview 1: 3ms
RegisterForAppOverview 2: 4ms
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1668654564)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1668654564)
Could not connect to X session manager: None of the authentication protocols specified are supported
Could not connect to X session manager: None of the authentication protocols specified are supported
Could not connect to X session manager: None of the authentication protocols specified are supported
Could not connect to X session manager: None of the authentication protocols specified are supported
Could not connect to X session manager: None of the authentication protocols specified are supported
Could not connect to X session manager: None of the authentication protocols specified are supported
Could not connect to X session manager: None of the authentication protocols specified are supported
Could not connect to X session manager: None of the authentication protocols specified are supported
Could not connect to X session manager: None of the authentication protocols specified are supported
GameAction [AppID 1703340, ActionID 1] : LaunchApp changed task to ProcessingInstallScript with ""
GameAction [AppID 1703340, ActionID 1] : LaunchApp changed task to SynchronizingCloud with ""
GameAction [AppID 1703340, ActionID 1] : LaunchApp changed task to SynchronizingControllerConfig with ""
GameAction [AppID 1703340, ActionID 1] : LaunchApp changed task to SiteLicenseSeatCheckout with ""
GameAction [AppID 1703340, ActionID 1] : LaunchApp changed task to CreatingProcess with ""
GameAction [AppID 1703340, ActionID 1] : LaunchApp waiting for user response to CreatingProcess ""
GameAction [AppID 1703340, ActionID 1] : LaunchApp continues with user response "CreatingProcess"
/bin/sh\0-c\0mangohud /home/REDACTED/.var/app/com.valvesoftware.Steam/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/reaper SteamLaunch AppId=1703340 -- /home/REDACTED/.var/app/com.valvesoftware.Steam/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-launch-wrapper -- '/run/media/REDACTED/Big Drive/SteamLibrary/steamapps/common/The Stanley Parable Ultra Deluxe/The Stanley Parable Ultra Deluxe.x86_64'\0
Game process added : AppID 1703340 "mangohud /home/REDACTED/.var/app/com.valvesoftware.Steam/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/reaper SteamLaunch AppId=1703340 -- /home/REDACTED/.var/app/com.valvesoftware.Steam/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-launch-wrapper -- '/run/media/REDACTED/Big Drive/SteamLibrary/steamapps/common/The Stanley Parable Ultra Deluxe/The Stanley Parable Ultra Deluxe.x86_64'", ProcID 2911, IP 0.0.0.0:0
chdir /run/media/REDACTED/Big Drive/SteamLibrary/steamapps/common/The Stanley Parable Ultra Deluxe
ERROR: ld.so: object '/home/REDACTED/.var/app/com.valvesoftware.Steam/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/gameoverlayrenderer.so' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32): ignored.
GameAction [AppID 1703340, ActionID 1] : LaunchApp changed task to WaitingGameWindow with ""
/bin/sh: line 1: mangohud: command not found
GameAction [AppID 1703340, ActionID 1] : LaunchApp changed task to Completed with ""
Game process removed: AppID 1703340 "mangohud /home/REDACTED/.var/app/com.valvesoftware.Steam/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/reaper SteamLaunch AppId=1703340 -- /home/REDACTED/.var/app/com.valvesoftware.Steam/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-launch-wrapper -- '/run/media/REDACTED/Big Drive/SteamLibrary/steamapps/common/The Stanley Parable Ultra Deluxe/The Stanley Parable Ultra Deluxe.x86_64'", ProcID 2911 
Uploaded AppInterfaceStats to Steam
Could not connect to X session manager: None of the authentication protocols specified are supported
Could not connect to X session manager: None of the authentication protocols specified are supported
Could not connect to X session manager: None of the authentication protocols specified are supported
Could not connect to X session manager: None of the authentication protocols specified are supported
Could not connect to X session manager: None of the authentication protocols specified are supported
Could not connect to X session manager: None of the authentication protocols specified are supported
GameAction [AppID 1703340, ActionID 2] : LaunchApp changed task to ProcessingInstallScript with ""
GameAction [AppID 1703340, ActionID 2] : LaunchApp changed task to SynchronizingCloud with ""
GameAction [AppID 1703340, ActionID 2] : LaunchApp changed task to SynchronizingControllerConfig with ""
GameAction [AppID 1703340, ActionID 2] : LaunchApp changed task to SiteLicenseSeatCheckout with ""
GameAction [AppID 1703340, ActionID 2] : LaunchApp changed task to CreatingProcess with ""
GameAction [AppID 1703340, ActionID 2] : LaunchApp waiting for user response to CreatingProcess ""
GameAction [AppID 1703340, ActionID 2] : LaunchApp continues with user response "CreatingProcess"
/bin/sh\0-c\0/usr/bin/mangohud /home/REDACTED/.var/app/com.valvesoftware.Steam/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/reaper SteamLaunch AppId=1703340 -- /home/REDACTED/.var/app/com.valvesoftware.Steam/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-launch-wrapper -- '/run/media/REDACTED/Big Drive/SteamLibrary/steamapps/common/The Stanley Parable Ultra Deluxe/The Stanley Parable Ultra Deluxe.x86_64'\0
Game process added : AppID 1703340 "/usr/bin/mangohud /home/REDACTED/.var/app/com.valvesoftware.Steam/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/reaper SteamLaunch AppId=1703340 -- /home/REDACTED/.var/app/com.valvesoftware.Steam/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-launch-wrapper -- '/run/media/REDACTED/Big Drive/SteamLibrary/steamapps/common/The Stanley Parable Ultra Deluxe/The Stanley Parable Ultra Deluxe.x86_64'", ProcID 2912, IP 0.0.0.0:0
chdir /run/media/REDACTED/Big Drive/SteamLibrary/steamapps/common/The Stanley Parable Ultra Deluxe
ERROR: ld.so: object '/home/REDACTED/.var/app/com.valvesoftware.Steam/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/gameoverlayrenderer.so' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32): ignored.
GameAction [AppID 1703340, ActionID 2] : LaunchApp changed task to WaitingGameWindow with ""
GameAction [AppID 1703340, ActionID 2] : LaunchApp changed task to Completed with ""
/bin/sh: line 1: /usr/bin/mangohud: No such file or directory
Game process removed: AppID 1703340 "/usr/bin/mangohud /home/REDACTED/.var/app/com.valvesoftware.Steam/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/reaper SteamLaunch AppId=1703340 -- /home/REDACTED/.var/app/com.valvesoftware.Steam/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-launch-wrapper -- '/run/media/REDACTED/Big Drive/SteamLibrary/steamapps/common/The Stanley Parable Ultra Deluxe/The Stanley Parable Ultra Deluxe.x86_64'", ProcID 2912 
Uploaded AppInterfaceStats to Steam
```

Comment: No idea, and can't test, but - did you try the [Flatpak-specific directions](https://github.com/flightlessmango/MangoHud#flatpak) from the readme?

Comment: Based on the that you reference `/usr/bin/mangohud: command not found` is appear you have not installed the FlatPak version of MangoHud. FlatPak installs are made so that they are a contained install and don't have access to a lot of the system, only what they need. The Steam Flatpak install won't have access to `/usr/bin/mangohud` and hence why the error occurs.

Answer (score 1):

So as it turns out, all I have to do is use the Flatpak version of MangoHud and now it's working nicely. So really, it's more like a permission issue.